# The correlation name 'o' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause

Tags: sql

I get the following error message when I run the SQL below, and I don't understand why this error message is coming up. Any correction to the below would be most welcome.

**The correlation name 'o' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.**

```
SELECT  TOP 100 o.[nOrderID] AS 'Order ID',
    o.[ReferenceNum],
    o.[ExternalReference],
    o.[Company],
    o.[cFullName],
    o.[cEmailAddress],
    o.[cPostCode],
    o.[dReceievedDate],
    o.[nStatus] AS 'status',
    o.[bProcessed] AS 'Processed',
    o.[dProcessedOn] AS 'ProcessedDate',
    o.[Source],
    o.[SubSource],
    o.[cCurrency] AS 'Currency',
    o.[fPostageCost] AS 'PostageCost',
    o.[Subtotal] AS 'Subtotal',
    o.[PostageCostExTax] AS 'PostageCostExTax',
    o.[CountryTaxRate],
    o.[fTax] AS 'Tax',
    oi.[ChannelSKU] AS 'OrderItemSKU',
    oi.[rowid] AS 'OrderItemId',
    oi.[fkChannelTitleId] AS 'OrderItemTitle',
    oi.[nQty] AS 'OrderItemQuantity',
    oi.[SalesTax] AS 'OrderItemSalesTax',
    oi.[TaxRate] AS 'OrderItemTaxRate',
    oi.[Cost] AS 'OrderItemCostExTax',
    oi.[CostIncTax] AS 'OrderItemCostIncTax',
    oi.[DispatchStockUnitCost],
    o.[PostalTrackingNumber] AS 'TrackingNumber',
    o.[BuyerPhoneNumber]

FROM [Order] o,
     [OrderItem] oi

INNER JOIN [Order] o

    ON o.[pkOrderID] = oi.[fkOrderID]

ORDER BY [nOrderID] DESC
```

Comment: Do you really want to join 2 instances of the Order table? If you do, they must have different table aliases.

Comment: How many times do you see the `order` table mentioned?

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems really clear and descriptive of the syntax problem.  Your question doesn't explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: your join condition should be `FROM [Order] o INNER JOIN     [OrderItem] oi
    ON o.[pkOrderID] = oi.[fkOrderID]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FROM` clause is:

```
FROM [Order] o,
     [OrderItem] oi INNER JOIN
     [Order] o
     ON o.[pkOrderID] = oi.[fkOrderID]
```

Just like the error message says, `o` is defined twice.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Presumably, you intend:

```
FROM [OrderItem] oi INNER JOIN
     [Order] o
     ON o.[pkOrderID] = oi.[fkOrderID]
```

Comment: It works now! thanks for the correction as you can tell I'm new to SQL and that FROM, thing gets me each time. I'll be sure to remember that next time.